# How to paste yanked filename to other application?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I'm able to paste text to other application using `CTRL + V`.

But when I try `:let @" = expand("%:p")`, then paste it to the other application it will just paste my last normal yanked text, instead the path of the file.

How I can paste the file path to other application from vim?

P.S.

When I paste the path to the vim instance, I can paste it using `"0p`.

Comment: What register do you use for the clipboard? + or *?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I just press ```y``` to yank, I got no idea about ```+``` or ```*```. How I can check what register I'm using?

Comment: Try `:help "+`; there’s probably an easier way but I cannot remember off the top of my head.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I think I am using the ```+```, I tried to look at  ```:reg``` the yanked text is also on the ```"+```.

Comment: I also noticed when I ```y```, the value of ```""```, ```"0``` and ```"+``` changed to the yanked value, but when I do ```:let @" = expand("%:p")``` only the ```""``` and ```"0``` is updated while the ```"+``` is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on which clipboard register is being used (`+` or `*`), you can use

```
let @+ = ...
```

The reason it « just works » when you press `y` to yank is that there is an option that lets the default yanks also go to the clipboard. See `:help 'clipboard'`

Comment: Thanks! Actually I learned from your comment above on my question that I can change the ```@"``` to ```@+``` :D. But the ```""``` and ```"0``` is not updated when I use ```@+```, only the ```"+``` is updated, but when I paste on the vim instance it will use the value on ```"+```, It seems a little bit weird for me right now. Maybe soon I will know why. BTW thanks again for the help.